# Add context to a Mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

What is the correct way to add context to a callback used in a Model query? For example...

```
function doSomething(param) {
    var magic = function(context, err, results) {
        if(err) { console.log('fail'); }
        else {
            // do the magic with context and results
        }
    }

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        var myObject = {'secret' : i};
        MyModel.find({number:param[i]}, magic(myObject, err, results));
    }
}
```

I'd like to loop through results for each query and have the context of myObject. The above solution does not work. 'err' and 'results' are not defined.

I normally do this with an anonymous function, but I can't rely on the context inside the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`err` and `results` are undefined because you arer passing a variables called `err` and `results` to `magic` which you never defined.

`MyModel.find` can't do anything with the result from `magic` because you don't return anything from it, you should be returning a function that takes `err` and `result`.

```
function doSomething(param) {
    var magic = function(context) {
        // return a function here
        return function(err, results) {
            if(err) { console.log('fail'); }
            else {
                // do the magic with context and results
            }
        };
    }

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        var myObject = {'secret' : i};
        // do not pass err or results to magic
        // they are not defined anywhere in this scope
        MyModel.find({number:param[i]}, magic(myObject));
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! the quirkiness of javascript that i'm still trying to master. thanks.